# Floated divs can't be positioned in bottom of its parent

Tags: html, css, css-float

Any idea how can I position my floated `div` in the bottom of its parent without using `position: absolute`, `display: flex` or `<table>`?

I'm rendering this page to generate a PDF and this solutions does not work: `position: absolute` can't handle the responsive size of contents, `display: flex` and `<table>` deconfigure on rendering. Only float seems to be accepted to get first and last `div` on the corners of my page.

```css
.third-adjust {
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    .third-adjust div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .third-adjust div:nth-child(1) {
        float: left;
    }
    .third-adjust div:nth-child(3) {
        float: right;
    }
    .sign img {
        max-width: 305px;
        max-height: 85px;
    }
    .text-bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .sign span {
        display: block;
        line-height: 16px;
    }
    .text-centered {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="line">
        <div class="third-adjust full text-centered">
            <div class="sign">
                <img style="margin-bottom: -40px; width: 123px; height: 85px;" src="https://dummyimage.com/123x85/000000/0011ff.png">
                <span style="font-size:14px" class="text-sign text-bold">Name</span>
                <span style="font-size:12px" class="text-sign">Position</span>
            </div>
            <div class="sign">
                <img style="margin-bottom: -20px; width: 155px; height: 71px;" src="https://dummyimage.com/155x71/000000/0011ff.png">
                <span style="font-size:14px" class="text-sign text-bold">Name</span>
                <span style="font-size:12px" class="text-sign">Position</span>
            </div>
            <div class="sign">
                <img style="margin-bottom: -10px; width: 201px; height: 58px;" src="https://dummyimage.com/201x58/000000/0011ff.png">
                <span style="font-size:14px" class="text-sign text-bold">Name</span>
                <span style="font-size:12px" class="text-sign">Position</span>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Thanks!